# How do I add an ID to a label tag in Zend Framework 1.9?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This:

```
$promo_details = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('promo_details');
$promo_details->setLabel('Promo Details: ')
      ->setDecorators($element_decorators)
      ->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'div'));
```

outputs:

```
<div id="promo_details-label">
  <label for="promo_details" class="optional">Promo Details:</label>
</div>
```

but I want to output:

```
<div id="label_row"> <-- changed the div#
  <label for="promo_details" class="optional">Promo Details:</label>
</div>
```

How do I tell Zend to not use the default ID it generates for "addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'div'))" but instead allow me to specify my own?  I can't find any information pointing me in the right direction.

@Royal BG ----

If I do:

```
->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'label_row'))
```

I get:

```
<div id="promo_details-label">
  <label for="promo_details" class="label_row optional">Promo Details:</label>
</div>
```

Where the class is added to the label instead of the div tag around the label, which is where I want it to go.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html according to the docs it says you can specify attributes in the array, did you try to specify id?

Comment: I assume you mean, array('tag' => 'div', 'id' => 'label_row')?  I tried that and adds an ID to the label, not the tag.  Frankly I find decorators extremely confusing in Zend and I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yep, according to the documentation you can specify a class `->addDecorator('HtmlTag',
                            array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element'));` so I assumed you may specify ID too. What does the rendered HTML looks like, when you try to specify id?

Comment: P.S.: I find Zend Forms as Anti-Framework and do not suggest people to use it at all. But it is just an oppinion

Comment: I agree with you.  I don't know why I'm using Zend Form at this point other than I need to learn it since my employee uses it in multiple places to manage their inventory, so I need to understand the framework inside and out.  Zend is cool, but I'm not liking how Forms are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set id for the label decorator's tag (see `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` `render()` - the id is hardcoded there as `label id + "-label"`).

To get html you want you can either:

1. Override `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` and provide sort of `setTagId()` there - certainly an overkill
2. Use `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` without tag option, and wrap it with `Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag` (with id needed) manually
3. Disable element's decorators at all and render with custom view script